# flink.api.table.TableException: Type is not supported

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I´m trying to use Flink Table API in scala. No errors in compiling time, but qhen i´m running the job in my flink cluster: `flink.api.table.TableException: Type is not supported:<GenericType<java.lang.Object>`

My maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-scala_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

My imports:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.table._
import org.apache.flink.api.table.{Row, Table, TableEnvironment}
```

My code:

```
// odo[(Long,String,Double,Long)]
val inputTable = odo.toTable(tableEnv,'ts,'ty, 'vl, 'dv)
val resultStream: Table = inputTable.where('ty === "Odometer").select('dv)
resultStream.toDataStream[Row].print
```

**Update**: I think it could be about Flink version(1.0.3), because when i do something like that:

```
val inputTable = odo.toTable(tableEnv, 'ts, 'ty, 'vl, 'dv)
val result = inputTable.select('dv,'vl.sum).where('dv == 111)
result.toDataStream[Row].print()
```

I have another exception: `org.apache.flink.api.table.TableException: Aggregate on stream tables is currently not supported.`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink's Table API does not support fields that contain a `GenericType` in `1.1-SNAPSHOT`. There is a [Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/2197) which implements this feature. It is very likely that it will be contained in the Flink 1.1 release.

Regarding your second exception: The exception is basically self explaining. You cannot do aggregations on streams so far. However, StreamSQL is under [development](https://flink.apache.org/news/2016/05/24/stream-sql.html).

Comment: I tried the Tables API with the new release of Flink(1.1.0), and a new exception has appeared. I do not know what dependency i need now: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/common/typeinfo/SqlTimeTypeInfo` and 
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.SqlTimeTypeInfo`

Comment: "odo" was an stream with watermarks, so i made "odo" an stream without watermarks, and this is the new exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.GenericTypeInfo cannot be cast to org.apache.flink.api.common.typeutils.CompositeType`

Comment: Your first problem sounds like wrong Maven dependency configuration. Your second problem like a bug. Could you open an issue for it. Maybe with a small code snippet to reproduce it. Then somebody can take a deeper look at it.

Comment: Thank you twalthr, i had an error in my frames, and now is working, except aggregation, still is not supported.

Comment: If you are interested in stream aggregations you can also watch the current development: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-11%3A+Table+API+Stream+Aggregations